# i need to pass Category Name with products Asp.Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

i have Categories Model and product Model. each product belong to categories. i need to pass the name of the Categories when product is display. i need categroies name as a title. but the Name looping with cards.

my Controller

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Categries(int id)
        {
var categries = _db.Products.Include(s => s.Categories).Where(X => X.CategoriesId == id).ToList();
        }
```

the action in the view

```
<div class="carousel carousel_dir" style="direction: ltr;" data-flickity='{ "groupCells": true }'>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {
        <div class="carousel-cell">
            <a asp-action="Categries" asp-route-id="@item.Id"> <img class="img_cell" src="~/Uploads/Categories/@item.Image"></a>
            <h5 class="img_cell_title">@item.CategoriesName</h5>
        </div>
    }
   
   
</div>
```

and the final view to display the products with each categories Name

```
//here the problem the categroies name. its loopnig i need to display just once//
 @foreach (var name in Model)
{
<h1>@name.Categories.CategoriesName</h1> 
}
<div class="card_contanier">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
 
        
        <div class="card">
            <img class="bg_img_card" src="~/img/site_img/Header_1.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="~/Uploads/Products/@item.Image" alt="" class="img_card">
            <h4 class="crad_mian_title">@item.Product_Name</h4>
            <p class="card_title">@item.Description</p>
            <div class="cards_description">
                <h6>@item.Price ريال</h6>
                <a href="">اطلبه الان</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    }

</div>
```

Comment: Your exact question is unclear. Please take a moment and rephrase your question a little bit to be more explicit?

Comment: It seems you didn't load the related data at all,you could check this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Comment: yes i edited that and i am including the categries name in the linq query. but whan i am including Categories in my view.chthml. its looping according to the cards and i wan't need that. all i need the display The categories name as a Title.